# Apply Formatting to TotalsRow using EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

Using EPPlus I can create the XSLX file and I can apply formatting to the data, but if I use a TotalsRow function, like SUM, then the formatting is not applied.

Does anyone know how to apply that formatting?

**Update:**

To load the data into a sheet and get the table I do the following (dtMain being a DataTable):

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp.xslx");

using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    //Create the Worksheet
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    //Read the table into a sheet
    var range = sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dtMain, true);

    sheet.Tables.Add(range, "data");
    //Now format the table...
    var tbl = sheet.Tables[0];
    tbl.ShowTotal = true;

    //create a custom style
    string stylename = "StyleName";
    var style = package.Workbook.Styles.CreateNamedStyle(stylename);

    tbl.Columns[SomeName].TotalsRowFunction = RowFunctions.Sum;

    style.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,###.00";

    //assign the style to the column
    tbl.Columns[SomeName].DataCellStyleName = stylename;
}

range.AutoFitColumns();

// save our new workbook and we are done!
package.Save();
```

Comment: How are you currently attempting to add formatting to the `ExcelRange`?

Comment: I updated my code to show how I apply formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the code: 
sheet.Cells[sheet.Dimension.End.Row, colcount].Style.Numberformat.Format = c.Format;

Full version:

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp.xslx");

using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    //Create the Worksheet
    var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    //Read the table into a sheet
    var range = sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dtMain, true);

    sheet.Tables.Add(range, "data");
    //Now format the table...
    var tbl = sheet.Tables[0];
    tbl.ShowTotal = true;

    //create a custom style
    string stylename = "StyleName";
    var style = package.Workbook.Styles.CreateNamedStyle(stylename);

    tbl.Columns[SomeName].TotalsRowFunction = RowFunctions.Sum;

    style.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,###.00";
    //apply style to totals row
    sheet.Cells[sheet.Dimension.End.Row, colcount].Style.Numberformat.Format = c.Format;

    //assign the style to the column
    tbl.Columns[SomeName].DataCellStyleName = stylename;
}

range.AutoFitColumns();

// save our new workbook and we are done!
package.Save();
```

Answer (score 4):

When you say "TotalsRow" do you mean a SUM column at the end of a row?  If so, you might be mixing up terms since the `TotalsRow` refers to a row at the BOTTOM of the table.  In order to show it you have to set `ShowTotal` to `true` as well.

If you actually want to sum up the columns into the last column you should apply a formula.

See if this helps:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TotalRows_Format_Test()
{
    //Throw in some data
    const string SomeName = "Totals";
    var dtMain = new DataTable("tblData");
    dtMain.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(int)));
    dtMain.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(int)));
    dtMain.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col3", typeof(int)));
    dtMain.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(SomeName, typeof(int)));

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var row = dtMain.NewRow();
        row["Col1"] = i;
        row["Col2"] = i * 10;
        row["Col3"] = i * 100;
        dtMain.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\Temp.xlsx");
    if (newFile.Exists)
        newFile.Delete();

    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
    {
        //Create the Worksheet
        var sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        //Read the table into a sheet
        var range = sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dtMain, true);

        sheet.Tables.Add(range, "data");
        //Now format the table...
        var tbl = sheet.Tables[0];

        //create a custom style
        string stylename = "StyleName";
        var style = package.Workbook.Styles.CreateNamedStyle(stylename);

        //Add formula for row total in COLUMN
        for (var i = 2; i <= dtMain.Rows.Count + 1; i++)
            sheet.Cells[i, 4].Formula = String.Format("SUM(A{0}:C{0})", i);

        //The totals row at the BOTTOM of the table
        tbl.Columns[SomeName].TotalsRowFunction = RowFunctions.Sum;
        tbl.ShowTotal = true;

        style.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,###.00";

        //assign the style to the column
        tbl.Columns[SomeName].DataCellStyleName = stylename;

    range.AutoFitColumns();

    // save our new workbook and we are done!
    package.Save();
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE (in response to comments)

I see what you mean now.  How about this:

```
tbl.TotalsRowCellStyle = stylename;
```

Comment: my question is applying FORMATTING to the TotalsRow, yes, that row that is added at the bottom of a table. I must have missed the ShowTotals when I cleaned the code prior to pasting it here. I will add it to the code above as it is in my application.

Comment: you will notice in your example that your TotalsRow is NOT formatted, but the rest of the values in the column is.

Comment: Thanks Ernie, but this works if I only need one format. Unfortunately my report includes percentages (##0.00%) as well as currency (#,##0.00). It seems my only solution is a "hack".

Comment: Ya, there doesnt seem to be an option to have multiple styles in epplus.  So, looks like the hack is the way to go.